# Creating instance for Eq typeclass for a custom type

Tags: haskell

I am learning Haskell through Chris Allen's Haskell Programming Book. Need help on the below (exercise question from Typeclasses chapter).
I need to create an instance of Eq typeclass for the data type:

```
data EitherOr a b = Hello a | Goodbye b
```

But when i am creating it as below, i am getting an error, which says, strangely, "parse error on input '='. Perhaps you need let in do block."

```
instance (Eq a,Eq b) => Eq (EitherOr a b) where
    (==) (Hello v) (Hello v') = v == v'
    (==) (Goodbye b) (Goodbye b') = b == b'
```

While attempting the exercises i also faced problem on below:

```
data Which a = ThisOne a | ThatOne a
```

I had to use the same name for argument (v, v') while defining (==) for both data constructors. I don't understand the reason.

```
instance Eq a => Eq (Which a) where
   (==) (ThisOne v) (ThisOne v') = v == v'
   (==) (ThatOne v) (ThatOne v') = v == v'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Writing a module with the above definitions and loading it in GHCi. at least, produces no compiler errors.

Comment: "I had to use..." - what do you mean by it? Was there any error otherwise?

Comment: You forgot the case where the first is a `Hello` and the second a `Goodbye` and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I provided the link below with screenshot of my code and error. I wrote the types and typeclasses in Notepadd++, didn't create modules. Also, i would welcome any learning suggestions for Haskell. As of now spending two hours a day on mentioned book. Also planning to join University Of Glasgow online course on futurelearn.

Comment: @user2159471 Please don't post descriptions, screenshots or reimaginings of your code. Copy&Paste actual code that actually exhibits the actual problem you're having. Actually. If the "real" code is too large, try to create a small code sample that still has the same problem (that way you'll often find things like typos before having to ask anyone else).

Comment: The issue here is that you are mixing TABs and spaces. Don't. Remove tabs for an easy fix. GHC should warn loudly about this, but does not (GHC 8.2.2) in your example: I get the warning only if I align the tab with 8 spaces, which fixes the error. But at that point it's too late! GHC should warn earlier -- indeed GHC 8.4.2 does!

Answer (score 4):

You've typo'd. Your code reads either:

```
(==) (Hello v) (Hello v') = v = v'  -- note the @v = v'@
```

or

```
(==) (Goodbye b) (Goodbye b') = b = b'  -- same problem
```

or potentially both.

---

Your second question is nonsense. You can define any variable name there, not just `v` and `v'`.

```
data MyEither a b = Lefty a | Righty b

instance (Eq a, Eq b) => Eq (MyEither a b) where
  (Lefty kumquat)   == (Lefty jebediah) = kumquat  == jebediah
  (Righty superman) == (Righty batman)  = superman == batman
```

Comment: Thanks Adam. I accept my second question was nonsense, i am not sure what did i miss, i tried multiple times that time. I tried again and it worked but still facing the same issue for first question. I took the screenshot and providing the link below. I wrote the the types and typeclasses in Notepad++. I loaded without EitherOr type, it works fine. I unloaded the file, added EitherOr and again tried to load. Facing the same error.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/iighrxe4mb6nax4/EqInstance.png?dl=0